# Cluster module loses shared net.Server handles on server.close()

Tags: node.js

I have a server/client application running that opens listeners using the core `net` and `tls` modules.  Each client connection to the server results in the server forking a new worker to interact with the client.  This can lead to multiple workers listening on the same port.  Typically this is not a problem as connections are distributed between the two, and they are both performing the same task internally. If worker 1 has created a listener on port 15000, then worker 2 is created and starts its own listener on port 15000, there aren't any issues.

However, if worker 1 has created a listener on port 15000, closed it, and then opened it again (fairly typical use case), and then worker 2 is created and tries to create a listener on port 15000 as well, then worker 2 gets an EADDRINUSE error.

It seems to be caused by the overall cluster losing the idea that this Server handle should be shared across all workers and that the newly created listener is owned only by the worker process that created it, thus the port isn't available to other workers.  (Maybe this isn't how the actual port sharing works across cluster workers, and this is just a misunderstanding on my part.)

I've written this small test that exhibits the issue.  It forks a new worker every 10 seconds where each worker will create a listener on port 16000, tear it down 15 seconds later, then, after 15 more seconds, create another listener on port 16000:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var net     = require('net');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    setInterval(function() {
        cluster.fork();
    }, 10000)
} else {
    var workerID = cluster.worker.id;
    var server;
    var setup = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' setting up listener');
        server = net.createServer(function(stream) {});
        server.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error on worker ' + workerID, err);
            console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' exiting')
            process.exit();
        });
        server.listen(16000);
        setTimeout(teardown,15000);
    }
    var teardown = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' closing listener');
        server.close();
        setTimeout(setup, 15000);
    }
    setup();
}
```

The behavior is seen when worker 1 attempts to recreate the listener (followed by subsequent workers as the loop continues):

```
Worker 1 setting up listener
Worker 2 setting up listener
Worker 1 closing listener
Worker 3 setting up listener
Worker 2 closing listener
Worker 1 setting up listener
Error on worker 1 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: null,
  port: 16000 }
Worker 1 exiting
Worker 4 setting up listener
Worker 3 closing listener
Worker 2 setting up listener
Error on worker 2 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: null,
  port: 16000 }
Worker 2 exiting
...
```

Any idea as to why this is happening or if there was a workaround for it?

**Edit to add an additional test case**

Some feedback has mentioned that the initial test case here could create an issue with polluting the event loop stack.  I've updated the test to the following which removes the majority of the timeouts and only leaves those necessary to demonstrate the issue at hand.

This new test case will spawn a new worker every 100ms.  Each worker will establish a listener on port 16000.  Worker 10, upon successfully establishing a listener, will set a timeout to tear down its listener 1s later.  At the time that worker 10 calls the teardown function, there should be 18 other workers listening on port 16000.  Worker 10 will not succeed again in setting up the listener.

In this particular case, without having a delay between a successful close and an attempted listen, this worker will cause the master to no longer be able to fork new workers; however, even adding a timeout of 500ms to the retry attempt of worker 10 (which will allow the master to continue forking workers), worker 10 will still not succeed in setting up a listener.  With the timeout, the newly forked workers are all able to successfully establish listeners.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var net     = require('net');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.fork();
    setInterval(function(){cluster.fork()},100);
} else {
    var workerID = cluster.worker.id;
    var server;
    var setup = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' setting up listener');
        server = net.createServer(function(stream) {});
        server.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error on worker ' + workerID, err);
            teardown();
        });
        if (workerID == 10) {
            server.listen(16000, function() {
                setTimeout(teardown, 1000);
            });
        } else {
            server.listen(16000);
        }
    }
    var teardown = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' closing listener');
        server.close(setup);
    }
    setup();
}
```

This test produces the following output:

```
Worker 1 setting up listener
Worker 2 setting up listener
Worker 3 setting up listener
Worker 4 setting up listener
Worker 5 setting up listener
Worker 6 setting up listener
Worker 7 setting up listener
Worker 8 setting up listener
Worker 9 setting up listener
Worker 10 setting up listener
Worker 11 setting up listener
Worker 12 setting up listener
Worker 13 setting up listener
Worker 14 setting up listener
Worker 15 setting up listener
Worker 16 setting up listener
Worker 17 setting up listener
Worker 18 setting up listener
Worker 19 setting up listener
Worker 10 closing listener
Worker 10 setting up listener
Error on worker 10 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: null,
  port: 16000 }
Worker 10 closing listener
Worker 10 setting up listener
Error on worker 10 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE null:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: null,
  port: 16000 }
Worker 10 closing listener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging with you I submit this answer.

Having no address specified for the worker causes the address to be null when its sent to listner function. Thus providing a unique address allows the module to identify the correct worker. But when its null it can't identify the correct worker to terminate when you call server.close()

Comment: I think this would be an acceptable solution if each worker only ever had a single listener.  However, in my case, a worker may have 3 or 4 listeners that have been successfully set up and only a single listener that has failed with this error.  Also, terminating a worker is the equivalent of removing an entire client connection, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Updated the answer let me know if that event close is emitted.

Comment: The 'close' event is being emitted.  Just to confirm, I added `server.on('close',setup)` and removed the callback from `server.close()` and still get the same result.

Comment: My next guess is to look at source code for net.js in the core modules for node. I'm looking at create server and going from there. Up front I find that cluster has a reference to address and doesn't seem to have a handler for if the address is provided. Going to have to keep digging to see if it's defined else where. But from the error on you log it shows address : null. That doesn't seem right to me. If we both look through the source we can probably find where net isn't releasing the address. I also haven't found where slaves are cleared as theres a slave array that gets created in cluster.

Comment: So I found in the core module address is assigned to null if not provided, try adding an. Incremental address scheme so they are not all pointing to null. This then the program might be able to clean it up since it'll have an address to reference. I'm spit balling at this point because I need to read more and figure out how a null address is handled in the ._listen2 function since that's what is setting up the cluster listeners.

Comment: Providing a different address to each worker (I went with 127.0.0.<workerID>) does prevent the EADDRINUSE issue (which makes sense, since there should be separate port ranges for each address), but simply providing them all with localhost or 127.0.0.1 still hits the same issue, despite the address no longer being null.  Also, would net.js actually hit the ._listen2 function if these listeners are all being established from workers and not master?  I could just be reading the overall listen() function incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, when listen is called it evaluates if the listen is being called on master or if it's exclusive. If true on either account it sends the address and port to listen2.

Comment: I think this does provide a solution for the question I asked, but not so much for the question I meant :\  The issue still exists that, given the same address for each worker, any number of new workers can open a listener on port X while an old worker who closes their listener on port X and attempts to reopen will fail with EADDRINUSE.  I've opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119648/sharing-net-ports-with-the-cluster-module) to try and track that more clearly.