# Sharing net ports with the Cluster module

Tags: node.js, sockets

Based on the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036310/cluster-module-loses-shared-net-server-handles-on-server-close), I'm trying to figure out why having multiple workers call `server.listen()` on the same port/address doesn't cause any issues, but having an old worker call `server.close()` followed by a `server.listen()` on the same port will repeatedly give the error `EADDRINUSE`.

It does not seem to be a case of the listener not closing correctly, as a `close` event is emitted, which is when I attempt to set up the new listener.  While this worker is getting `EADDRINUSE`, newly spawned workers are able call `server.listen()` with no issues.

Here is a simple test that will demonstrate the problem.  As workers are forked every 100ms, they will establish a listener on port 16000.  When worker 10 is forked, it will establish a timeout to tear down its listener after 1s.  Once a `close` event is emitted, it will attempt to call `server.listen()` on port 16000 again and get the `EADDRINUSE` error.  For consistency, this test explicitly provides the same address during binding to avoid any potential issues with core modules dealing with a `null` address.

This particular implementation will cause worker 10 to then take up all cycles once it hits the error during binding, thereby keeping the master process from forking new workers.  If a delay is added before calling `server.listen()`, worker 10 will still continue to hit `EADDRINUSE` while the master continually forks new workers that are capable of establishing listeners.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var net     = require('net');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    setInterval(function(){cluster.fork()},100);
} else {
    var workerID = cluster.worker.id;
    var server;
    var setup = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' setting up listener');
        server = net.createServer(function(stream) {});
        server.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error on worker ' + workerID, err);
            teardown();
        });
        if (workerID == 10) {
            server.listen(16000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
                console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' listener established');
                setTimeout(teardown, 1000);
            });
        } else {
            server.listen(16000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
                console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' listener established');
            });
        }
    }
    var teardown = function() {
        console.log('Worker ' + workerID + ' closing listener');
        server.close(setup);
    }
    setup();
}
```

Initial output from this test case:

```
Worker 1 setting up listener
Worker 1 listener established
Worker 2 setting up listener
Worker 2 listener established
Worker 3 setting up listener
Worker 3 listener established
Worker 4 setting up listener
Worker 4 listener established
Worker 5 setting up listener
Worker 5 listener established
Worker 6 setting up listener
Worker 6 listener established
Worker 7 setting up listener
Worker 7 listener established
Worker 8 setting up listener
Worker 8 listener established
Worker 9 setting up listener
Worker 9 listener established
Worker 10 setting up listener
Worker 10 listener established
Worker 11 setting up listener
Worker 11 listener established
Worker 12 setting up listener
Worker 12 listener established
Worker 13 setting up listener
Worker 13 listener established
Worker 14 setting up listener
Worker 14 listener established
Worker 15 setting up listener
Worker 15 listener established
Worker 16 setting up listener
Worker 16 listener established
Worker 17 setting up listener
Worker 17 listener established
Worker 18 setting up listener
Worker 18 listener established
Worker 19 setting up listener
Worker 19 listener established
Worker 10 closing listener
Worker 10 setting up listener
Error on worker 10 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 16000 }
Worker 10 closing listener
Worker 10 setting up listener
Error on worker 10 { [Error: bind EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:16000]
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 16000 }
Worker 10 closing listener
```

Comment: If you listen to port 0 instead of 16000 (meaning that the listening port will be random, but all workers will be using that same random port), the error isn't being thrown, so I wonder if [this code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cee4c25c9281d106f80b20ba7854bf9003f9357a/lib/net.js#L1310-L1315) may be causing the error (although it doesn't make a whole lot of sense because AFAICS it would mean that there's mismatch in ports, which there shouldn't be).

Comment: By using port 0 instead of 16000, all of the initial listeners are established on the same port (in my case, 53230), but whenever worker 10 starts up another listener with port 0, it seems to increment the port being listened on (53230 for the initial listen, 53231 for the second listen, etc.).

Comment: Ugh, I didn't realize that. It sounds like calling `server.listen()` in a worker a second time is fraught with issues.

Comment: Can you print out the socket or server object itself? That might give you more details as to why it's trying to call `bind` again. I'm guessing that in the case of the other workers, they know that the socket _exists_ so they avoid calling _bind_, but in case of worker **10** it falsely believes the socket has not been bound. The question is figuring out where in this stateful operation that mistake is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be internal to the cluster module and is being tracked via [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6693) on the node Github.

Issue has now been updated and closed as fixed.

Update: this fix is available in v6.2.1